# HELP!! OVERHEATING 2000 CIVIC EK HATCHBACK

Tags: overheating

My Hatchback was over heating A LOT OF SMOKE. Heater stopped working, realized it was my heater core hose. I replaced it and it’s still over heating but no smoke. If I drive like 40mph it’s starts overheating. Then I put the heater on cold and it goes down. My heater works fine now and it’s hotter now. But the line still goes up like it’s overheating. If I park and put the heater on hot it’s perfect but once I pull off it gives me this issue. ANY TIPS?!! HELPPP

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Did you properly bleed the cooling system?

Comment: Like flush it ?

Answer (score 1):

No, flushing is not bleeding.

Bleeding is where the excess trapped air is removed from the water pipes to allow the fluid to flow correctly, air pockets can stop the flow causing overheating.

Some cars have small bleed valves fitted at high points in the cooling system for this reason.

Flushing is where the cooling system has any loose deposits washed out of the pipes, radiators and block.